# Is there a way to give away your coins when you leave this game?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

Sadly I can't keep up with Game of War. My husband plays all the time so I'd like to give him all of my coins. Is there a way to do this??

Comment: It seems not. The best you can do is give all your rss. Otherwise, give him your account and let him use yours as a farm or a secondary... Additionally, there are sites online which facilitate the selling of your GoW account.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can only send resources like wood, stone, iron and silver through the market. But you cannot send gold to other players.